# Line numbers in malloc trace using Pin

Tags: c++, intel-pin

I am working on Pintool for tracing malloc/free operations. From the ManualExamples/malloc_trace.cpp I was able to print out malloc/free in a sample code.

I was wondering if there is a way to print the line numbers in the source code where malloc/free is encountered. In the following malloctrace.cpp where a malloc is instrumented, can I add any parameter or another call to print the line number.

```
if (RTN_Valid(mallocRtn))
 {   
     RTN_Open(mallocRtn);
     // Instrument malloc() to print the input argument value and the return value.
     RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Arg1Before,
                    IARG_ADDRINT, MALLOC,
                    IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0, IARG_END); 
     RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)MallocAfter,
                   IARG_FUNCRET_EXITPOINT_VALUE, IARG_END);
    RTN_Close(mallocRtn);
}
```

In DebugTrace.cpp, I see there is a function

```
 string FormatAddress(ADDRINT address, RTN rtn)
```

that can print the line number for a RTN. Is there a way to use this function to get the line numbers for malloc?

// EDITED

I have written a new function

```
 VOID printline(ADDRINT instr_ptr )
    {
// get source line

        INT32 line;
        string file,s ;

        PIN_LockClient();
         LEVEL_PINCLIENT::PIN_GetSourceLocation(instr_ptr, NULL, &line, &file);
        PIN_UnlockClient();

        if (file != "") 
        {   
        TraceFile << file << " " << decstr(line) << endl;           
        }   
}
```

and I'm calling in my main function

```
 RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)printline,
                       IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_END);
```

Is this the correct way to use "GetSourceLocation" function, I've tried this, it compiles fine but does not print the line numbers.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following API:

```
  void LEVEL_PINCLIENT::PIN_GetSourceLocation(ADDRINT   address,
        INT32 *     column,
        INT32 *     line,
        string *    fileName
    )
```

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pin/docs/25945/Pin/html/group__DEBUG__API.html

Compile using $ gcc -g program.cpp -o program -gdwarf-2

Answer (score 0):

You can get very close very easily: you can get the return address from malloc with IARG_RETURN_IP , and use this as input to PIN_GetSourceLocation(). This will usually lead you to the line after the malloc.

Getting the real line is  far more complex, so if what I suggested is good enough I'd stick to that

Comment: I've been trying using IARG_RETURN_IP in this way, it doesnt work, is this the right way?                                                                          RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)printline,  
                              IARG_ADDRINT, IARG_RETURN_IP,   
                              IARG_FUNCRET_EXITPOINT_VALUE, 
                               IARG_END);

Comment: 1. Try using IPOINT_BEFORE 2. You don't seem to use the IARGs correctly. I recommend creating another question about using IARGs after searching for an example in the pin kit.